# How to check 'if condition' in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a variable called value.

It will only have either true or false value. (Not 1 or 0).

I need to execute the if condition only if value is true.

```
  <xsl:if test="value = true">
           //perform action  
      </xsl:if>
```

Now , the If condition is executing even when value is  false. Please suggest valid changes.

Comment: A [mcve] showing how exactly the variable gets its value would be helpful.

Comment: I'am using a mapper function and converting JSON data to XML. So getting the value from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variable is already a Boolean value (i.e. not a *string* of either "true" or "false"), then you can do simply:

```
<xsl:if test="$value">
    <!-- do something -->
</xsl:if>
```

---

If the variable is a string, then use:

```
<xsl:if test="$value='true'">
    <!-- do something -->
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: The variable is a string that contains either true or false.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: The explanation of why `$value = true` doesn't work is that `true` means `child::true`. It looks for a child element named `true`, and it there isn't one, it compares `$value` with the empty sequence, and a comparison of a string with the empty sequence is always false.

Comment: Is there any other way to check this? Because I have the template in DB and when I try to update the template,`update Template
set TemplateXSLT='// <xsl:if test="$value='true'"> // where condition ..`- This is the update query. And when I try to update the query, sql server is considering the singlequote before true to be the end of the update statement single quote and throwing error. @michael.hor257k

Comment: I suppose you need to find a way to escape the quotes in the language you're using (which I am not familiar with). It has nothing to do with the question here. I don't know of a way to perform this test in XSLT without using both single and double quotes.